# Is it possible to use an existing field into a matrix?

Tags: matrix, field, fieldtypes, drop-down

I'm trying to reuse a dropdown field inside of a matrix. I've already created a field which has hundreds of dropdown values. I want to be able to select from this dropdown field for each item of a matrix. So instead of having to re create this field for each matrix block, is there a way I can copy/paste a field to a matrix field?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [neo](https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-neo/blob/master/README.md) Plugin or you can copy and paste the field settings manually from one field to your matrix field in your database interface. In your `craft_fields` table there is a column `settings` you can search for your field handle and copy the settings to your new field.

You'll not be able to do this without a custom plugin or copy pasting the values via SQL in any way